# admin controller action not redirecting after imagemagick operations

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I have created an admin module for CRUD operations and in the controller I am processing uploaded image using Imagemagick.

But After sometime controller action stops and I can only see loader icon. Even after completion of all Imagemagick processes controller is not redirecting to Grid page.

What would be the problem?

Comment: Hey man, how someone can help you without seeing any code?

Comment: try to see the browser console it may help